# How to get the rowcount from php file in android

Tags: php, android

I'm comparing the username and password from the user input to the database data, and I used count to check if it is equal to 1 or 0.

If it's equal to 1, the editText should be set to 1, and if it's 0 it should be set to 0.

My problem is, it's always set to 0 even if the username and password is correct.

here is the name value pair and connection to the database:

```
    username = etlogUsername.getText().toString();
    password = etlogPassword.getText().toString();
    String output = "";

//setting the NameValuePair
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

            //adding the string variables inside the nameValuePairs
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_password", password));
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://thesis-account.byethost7.com/workout_select_username.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            //getting the response
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            //setting up the entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            is = entity.getContent();
```

here is the json that will read the data:

```
JSONArray jArray= new JSONArray(output);

            for(int i = 0;  i <jArray.length() ; i++){
                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                COUNT_user_id = json.getInt("num_rows");

                if(COUNT_user_id == 1)
                {
                 isEqual = true;
                }
            }
            etlogUsername.setText(COUNT_user_id+"");
```

and here is the php file:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS num_rows FROM tbl_users
WHERE user_username='{ $username}' && user_password = '{$password}' ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Umm, your php code isn't doing anything with a username and password.  Neither is your java, other than adding it to the request.  So from what you've given us, if should be returning every row in tbl_students.  If there's actually a problem with your authentication code, you'd need to give us that to find it.

Comment: ohh, i've put different php code. i'll edit it wait.

Comment: or die(mysql_error()) needs adding right before the closing semicolon in the $sql to eliminate any errors there. I see no reason why that shouldnt work otherwise.

Comment: Well, the one major error I see here is your name.  In your java code you're looking for the name "COUNT(user_id)" for the result.  I don't think it would use that-  I don't think the count would have a name at all, just an ordinal.  If you want to use a name, do SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS numrows.  Then call it numrows in your java

Comment: @Gabe Sechan - I've changed it to numrows, but the output is still 0.

Comment: What is the response string you're getting back?